# eclipse (ADT) theme broken after installing subversive plugin

Tags: eclipse, svn, adt

I downloaded the ADT (android developer tools, basically an eclipse juno with the android plugins already installed).
Now I'm trying to install the SVN plugin. But everytime I install the plugin, the user interface of my eclipse seems to be broken. The toolbar looks weird. By looking in the settings i noticed that no themes were available anymore.
image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Suf3.png

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This happend to me if i installed any plugin..

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue and seems to be unsolvable at the moment:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41126